# Unable setup keystore in Spring Boot Eureka Client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, mtls

I have Spring boot netflix Eureka Server. in the server I have configured client TLS authentication as true.

```
##Server Properties
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/mTLS_Server_Keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<pass>
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=eurekaserver
server.http.enabled=false  # Force disable HTTP

server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore/mTLS_CA.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=<pass>
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
```

This works fine. Now my goal is to setup a netlflix eurkea client which will register with this eureka server.

```
#Client Properties
eureka.client.tls.enabled=true
eureka.client.tls.key-store=classpath:keystore/mTLS_Client_Keystore.p12
eureka.client.tls.key-store-type=PKCS12
eureka.client.tls.key-store-password=<pass>
eureka.client.tls.keyAlias=eurekaclient

eureka.client.tls.trust-store=classpath:truststore/auth_service_truststore.jks
eureka.client.tls.trust-store-type=JKS
eureka.client.tls.trust-store-password=<pass>
```

now
I have verified password and keys for mTLS_Client_Keystore.p12 with openssl, it is as expected.
But I am unable to start my app the error is a below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/config/DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs]: Factory method 'restTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' threw exception with message: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:643) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.soumyadip.storemanagement.authenticate.AuthenticateServiceApplication.main(AuthenticateServiceApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs]: Factory method 'restTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' threw exception with message: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:91) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1050) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:275) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(SSLContextBuilder.java:366) ~[httpcore5-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(SSLContextBuilder.java:409) ~[httpcore5-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.configuration.SSLContextFactory.createSSLContext(SSLContextFactory.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-commons-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.setupTLS(DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.restTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs(DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:859) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:939) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Core.engineDoFinal(PBES2Core.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.lambda$engineGetKey$0(PKCS12KeyStore.java:371) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore$RetryWithZero.run(PKCS12KeyStore.java:257) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:361) ~[na:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

It is not a password issue, i have verified that, I have used a RSA 2048 key as private key.
I do not see any issue with my private key or key store, but i see padding exception.

pom.xml file is

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have the PKCS12 file is generated in the same way I have generated for eureka server which has no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution

Need to add property named `eureka.client.tls.key-password` even if key password is same as keystore password.